# C++17 Singleton Implementation with Inline variable

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17, singleton, inline-variable

I recently came across this article: https://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf I'm curious to know if the problems discussed in the article are still relevant when considering the introduction of C++17's inline variable feature.

As C++17 brought new features and improvements, particularly the ability to declare inline variables, I wonder if some of the issues addressed in the 2004 article have been mitigated or changed by this enhancement.

Additionally, I am interested in implementing the Singleton design pattern in C++17 and want to ensure that I follow the best practices and leverage the latest language features. Could someone provide insights into how C++17's inline variables might affect the problems presented in the 2004 article?

Furthermore, I would appreciate guidance on the most efficient and robust way to implement the Singleton pattern in C++17. Since inline variables are now available, I'm curious if they can play a role in the Singleton implementation for better performance and thread safety.

Any help, clarifications, or code examples related to both C++17's inline variable and Singleton pattern implementation would be highly valuable. Thank you in advance!

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance () {
    Singleton* tmp = pInstance;
    ...                            // insert memory barrier
    if (tmp == 0) {
         Lock lock;
         tmp = pInstance;
         if (tmp == 0) {
             tmp = new Singleton;
             ...                  // insert memory barrier
             pInstance = tmp;
         }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: I think the mentioned issues were amended with C++11, which made `static` local variables thread-safe to initialise?